# Show that $\displaystyle\int _{(0,1) \times (0,1)} \frac {xy } {(x^2+y^2)^2 } d(\mu \times \lambda )$ does not exist?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I want to show that $$\int _{(0,1)\times (0,1) }  \frac {xy } {(x^2+y^2)^2 } d(\mu \times \lambda )$$ doesn't exist, but don't know how to do it.

First thing would be to try to show that the the iterated aren't equal.But in this case they are, since in any order, they both equals zero.

---

Does $f \in L^1 (\mu \times \lambda ) $ imply $$\int d \mu\int    \left|\frac {xy } {(x^2+y^2)^2 } \right| d \lambda < \infty$$ ?

---

I know $$\int d \mu\int    \left|
\frac {xy } {(x^2+y^2)^2 } \right| d \lambda < \infty$$ is a suficient condition for $f \in L^1 (\mu \times \lambda ) $ but is it also necessary?

[I can show that $\int d \mu\int    |\frac {xy } {(x^2+y^2)^2 } | d \lambda = \infty$]

If this is not the case, then what?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** make the polar coordinates change of variables.

You will get something of the form
$$
\int_{[0,\pi/2)} d\theta \int_{(0,\epsilon)} dr \frac{F(\theta)}{r^2} + O(1)
$$

Comment: Sorry, but what am I supposed to do with this?

Comment: as $\int_{(0,\epsilon)} \frac{dr}{r^2}$ diverges, so does yours.

Comment: But this says that the iterated absolute integral diverges, right? What about the integral with respect to the product measure?

Comment: @Alexander according to the Fubini theorem (here everything is positive so you can apply it) the integral according to the product measure converges iff the iterated integral does.

Comment: Ok, great, so if the integrand is positive, then convergence of the iterated integrals is necessary and suficient.